Deploying an application using argo cd without git/helm repo
In my organization, I have a ci/cd process for deploying the applications with jenkins. In my ci/cd pipeline the helm chart for a specific service is generated dynamically using the environment values and secrets stored in the postgres database, values are fetched from this database and then the chart is generate and applied to the targeted cluster using the helm install or helm upgrade command and after the services are deployed the generated kubernetes manifests are not stored in any helm or git repo.
Now I want to use the arog-cd for the CD part of the pipeline, so is it possible to deploy the application while still maintaining the current architecture of the infrastructure (not storing the k8s manifests in repo) and just applying the dynamically generated manifests to the cluster through argo-cd?
Currently as of now I am trying to figure out the architecture so that argo can be applied without making changes to the current architecture

I assume you use Jenkins to do all the DB fetching, chart generation, etc...? If  so, it is impossible to do the same with ArgoCD since ArgoCD is a GitOps tool, not a build tool. The chart should already be generated for ArgoCD to deploy it. You could either search for a different tool or consider performing the chart generation when your image is being built. For example, while you branch build/master build is being run and you image is being created, you could also perform the DB calls in the same pipeline, then bundle the final result into a Git tag. You can then deploy the tag into your cluster using ArgoCD.

In my current ci/cd pipeline the charts are dynamically generated after the image creation and then I use helm install or helm upgrade command to apply those charts, I need a way that i can implement argo for the deployment part only without having to store these charts

Shailendra Sharma yes, it's possible to use Argo CD without storing Kubernetes manifests in a repository. Argo CD supports applying dynamically generated manifests directly to your cluster. You can configure Argo CD to sync with the dynamically generated manifests from your CI/CD pipeline, ensuring your deployments stay in sync with your application changes.

could you please give me more details on this?
